# Interesting matrix construction question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

> We are told that an $n \times n$ matrix $P$ satisfies $P^3=P$. Can we construct such a matrix $P$?

Of course, we see that $-1,0,1$ are its only eigenvalues and, thus, a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $0,1,-1$ would do. However, if I were told that the given matrix should not have $0,1,-1$ as its diagonal elements, then what would be the way out?

Comment: Conjugate it with an invertible matrix.

Comment: Real matrix I suppose ?

Comment: All projections work, since $P^2 = P$ for them, I don't know about the rest though.

Comment: Yes @nicomezi it is real

Comment: Didn't get it  @Giuseppe

Comment: "To conjugate" a matrix $A$ with an invertible matrix $P$ means taking $PAP^{-1}$.

Comment: Can such matrices be nondiagonalisable?

Comment: @J_P No: Since $P$ satisfies $0 = P^3 - P$, its minimal polynomial divides $x^3 - x = (x - 1) x (x + 1)$ and so has distinct linear factors.

Comment: @Travis Sadly, we didn't mention minimal polynomials in our lin alg course so I don't really know much about this.

Comment: @Travis I posted an answer before down below that I think is in the same vein, do you think it holds up?

Comment: Yes (though I confess I didn't read all of the summations carefully), and +1. As a matter of exposition, I would have favored just writing out the $n = 3$ case explicitly, since it's much easier to read but still contains all of the features of the general problem, and then mention at the end that the same technique can be applied just as well to arbitrary $n > 1$.

Comment: @Travis Ok, great! Just one more question, in the example you provided here you used the third roots of unity but I used the second (if we set $n+1=3$), are these two approaches equivalent?

Comment: In fact, specializing your method to (again, your) $n = 3$ almost gives a one-line proof: "For every $v$, $$v = (I - P^2) v + \frac{1}{2}(P^2 + P) v + \frac{1}{2}(P^2 - P) v$$, but direct computation gives that each of the terms on the r.h.s. is an eigenvector of $P$, so every $v$ is a sum of eigenvectors, that is, $P$ is diagonalizable."

Comment: I was actually a little careless in writing down my argument (for one it would imply that the eigenvalues of $P$ were the third roots of unity, which is not the case): Of course, the eigenspace decomposition is unique.

Comment: @Travis Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Any matrix $P$ satisfying $P^3 = P$ satisfies $f(P) = 0$, where $f(x) = (x + 1) x (x - 1)$, so the minimal polynomial $m_p$ of $P$ divides $(x + 1) x (x - 1)$. In particular, $m_p(x)$ has distinct linear factors, equivalently, it is diagonalizable. Now, appeal to the Jordan normal form.

> For any solution $P$ of $P^3 = P$ there is some invertible matrix $Q$ satisfying $$P = Q \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\&\ddots\\&&\lambda_n} Q^{-1},$$ where (per the observation in the question, or using our observation that $m_p \mid (x + 1) x (x - 1)$)  $\lambda_i \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$. Conversely, substituting shows that any $P$ of this form satisfies $P^3 = P$, and so matrices of that form comprise precisely the solutions of the equation.

Comment: By listing three lambdas on the diagonal, it seems that you're implying that the matrix is $3\times3$. Shouldn't you have something like $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\ldots$, $\lambda_n$ along the diagonal?

Comment: Yes, and I've adjusted the answer accordingly---thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

The point of this answer is to show that such a $P$ is diagonalisable.

Let $P$ represent a linear transformation such that $P^{n+1}=P$. If we denote the $n$-th roots of unity by$$\omega_{n,k}=\exp\left(2\pi i\frac{k}{n}\right)$$
then obviously the only eigenvalues of $P$ can be the $\omega_{n,k}$ and $0$.

We can write the identity transformation as as:
$$
\mathrm{Id}=\mathrm{Id}-P^n+\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}R_r
$$
where
$$
R_r=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega_{n,k}^rP^{n-k}
$$
Indeed:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}R_r=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega_{n,k}^rP^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\omega_{n,k}^r\right)P^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\delta_{k,0}P^{n-k}=P^n
$$
For the second equality I summed the geometric series when $k\neq0$, while $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.

At the same time, notice that
\begin{align}
PR_r&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega_{n,k}^rP^{n-k+1}=\frac{1}{n}\omega_{n,r}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\omega_{n,k-1}^rP^{n-(k-1)}+\frac{1}{n}\omega_{n,0}^r
P^{n+1}=\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\omega_{n,r}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\omega_{n,k}^rP^{n-k}+\frac{1}{n}\omega_{n,r}\,\omega_{n,n-1}^rP^{n-(n-1)}=\omega_{n,r}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega_{n,k}^rP^{n-k}=\omega_{n,r}R_r
\end{align}
And:
$$
R_r^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}(\omega_{n,k}\omega_{n,l})^rP^{2n-k-l}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\omega_{n,k+l}^rP^{n-(k+l-n)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\omega_{n,m}^rP^{n-m}=R_r
$$
Here I used the fact that there are exactly $n$ ways to choose a pair $(k,l)$ such that $k+l=x\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,n$ for any given $0\leq x\leq n-1$ and also the facts that $\omega_{n,k+l}=\omega_{n,(k+l\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,n)}$ and $P^{n-(k+l-n)}=P^{n-(k+l\,\,\mathrm{mod}\,\,n)}$ (all this is perhaps a bit finicky to show, but it does work - if you want to convince yourself, the simplest way is probably to treat seperately the cases when $k+l\geq n$ and $k+l< n$).
Also, we have $P(\mathrm{Id}-P^n)=0$. If we take some $v$, we find:
$$
v=(\mathrm{Id}-P^n)v+\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}R_rv
$$
This is a decomposition of an arbitrary vector into eigenvectors (the $(\mathrm{Id}-P^n)v$ and $R_rv$), and so if we pick arbitrary bases for the eigenspaces $E_P(0)$ and $E_P(\omega_{n,r})$, these together form a basis for the entire space. Therefore, $P$ is diagonalisable and $\mathrm{Id}-P^n,R_r$ are its associated projectors. Now you can proceed as Giuseppe Negro suggested, by conjugating appropriate diagonal matrices with invertible ones. This should give all possible matrices such that $P^{n+1}=P$.